# OSB12 outbound context variable with null value

Tags: xml, soap, runtime, osb

I have exposed in three different osb12c environments (testing, preproductionnd production) two other services. The problem is that in production these services respond with this error:OSB-382046: Failed to marshall the value of context variable "outbound" to XML: error: Unexpected element: CDATA.
Reviewing the production and pre-production log where the services do respond correctly, the only thing out of the ordinary that I can see is that in production the outbound variable throughout the journey has a null value. and I have no idea why something like this could be happening in that environment. So I would appreciate if someone could know an explanation for this and be able to solve this situation.
**Error described in the log:**

```
[2022-03-11T15:40:10.387-03:00] [osb_p_bcf_man11] [NOTIFICATION] [OSB-382183] [oracle.osb.pipeline.kernel.router] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '143' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: d0953d70-4a1a-439f-9cbb-90263decb764-0000c561,0:3] [APP: Service Bus Test Framework] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [FlowId: 0000NxuHz981nZYVLq6UOA1Y9wVF008D4s] [[
 [OSB Tracing] Exiting route node with fault: 
<con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
  <con:errorCode>OSB-382046</con:errorCode>
  <con:reason>Failed to marshall the value of context variable "outbound" to XML: error: Unexpected element: CDATA</con:reason>
  <con:location>
    <con:node>RouteNode</con:node>
    <con:path>request-pipeline</con:path>
  </con:location>
</con:fault>
]]
```

**Log snippet in production**

```
[2022-03-11T15:40:10.271-03:00] [osb_p_bcf_man11] [NOTIFICATION] [OSB-382163] [oracle.osb.pipeline.kernel.router] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '143' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: d0953d70-4a1a-439f-9cbb-90263decb764-0000c561,0:3] [APP: Service Bus Test Framework] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [FlowId: 0000NxuHz981nZYVLq6UOA1Y9wVF008D4s] [[
 [OSB Tracing] Entering stage Nombre de Artefacto with message context: 
 [MessageContextImpl  attachments="<con:attachments xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context"/>"
 inbound="<con:endpoint name="ProxyService$INT_OSB_CustomerManagement$PartialUpdate$VAC$Proxy$VAC_PartialUpdate" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
  <con:service>
    <con:operation>PartialUpdate</con:operation>
  </con:service>
  <con:transport>
    <con:uri>VAC_PartialUpdate</con:uri>
    <con:mode>request-response</con:mode>
    <con:qualityOfService>best-effort</con:qualityOfService>
    <con:request xsi:type="sb:SBRequestMetaDataXML" xmlns:sb="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/sb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <tran:headers xsi:type="sb:SBRequestHeadersXML" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports"/>
      <tran:encoding xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">utf-8</tran:encoding>
    </con:request>
    <con:response xsi:type="sb:SBResponseMetaDataXML" xmlns:sb="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/sb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <tran:headers xsi:type="sb:SBResponseHeadersXML" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports"/>
      <tran:response-code xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">0</tran:response-code>
    </con:response>
  </con:transport>
  <con:security>
    <con:transportClient>
      <con:username>&lt;anonymous></con:username>
    </con:transportClient>
  </con:security>
</con:endpoint>"
 **outbound="null"**
 fault="null"
 header="<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <req_hdr:requestHeader xmlns:req_hdr="ar.com.cablevision.common.RequestHeader">
    <req_hdr:origin>
      <req_hdr:org>UNKNOWN2</req_hdr:org>
      <req_hdr:system>UNKNOWN2</req_hdr:system>
      <req_hdr:subsystem>UNKNOWN2</req_hdr:subsystem>
    </req_hdr:origin>
    <req_hdr:security>
      <req_hdr:token>UNKNOWN</req_hdr:token>
    </req_hdr:security>
    <req_hdr:message>
      <req_hdr:correlationId>N3f572585.134bd7a3.1d.17f7a43c82b.N790b</req_hdr:correlationId>
    </req_hdr:message>
    <req_hdr:operationRoot>PartialUpdate</req_hdr:operationRoot>
    <req_hdr:businessEntity>unknown</req_hdr:businessEntity>
    <req_hdr:businessId>unknown</req_hdr:businessId>
    <req_hdr:ESBFlags>
      <req_hdr:DBErrorLogMode>ALWAYS</req_hdr:DBErrorLogMode>
      <req_hdr:EXPLogBAM>false</req_hdr:EXPLogBAM>
      <req_hdr:EXPAuthenticate>false</req_hdr:EXPAuthenticate>
      <req_hdr:EXPvalidateHeader>false</req_hdr:EXPvalidateHeader>
      <req_hdr:EXPdebugTrace>true</req_hdr:EXPdebugTrace>
      <req_hdr:EXPLogRequestOnFault>false</req_hdr:EXPLogRequestOnFault>
      <req_hdr:EXPLogRequestOnFaultLogger/>
      <req_hdr:EXPFlags>
        <req_hdr:validateRequest>true</req_hdr:validateRequest>
        <req_hdr:validateResponse>true</req_hdr:validateResponse>
        <req_hdr:logRequest>true</req_hdr:logRequest>
        <req_hdr:logResponse>true</req_hdr:logResponse>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerStrictMode>false</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerStrictMode>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogMode>ONCE</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogMode>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogVerbosity>DEBUG</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogVerbosity>
      </req_hdr:EXPFlags>
      <req_hdr:LINFlags>
        <req_hdr:validateRequest>true</req_hdr:validateRequest>
        <req_hdr:validateResponse>true</req_hdr:validateResponse>
        <req_hdr:logRequest>true</req_hdr:logRequest>
        <req_hdr:logResponse>true</req_hdr:logResponse>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerStrictMode>false</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerStrictMode>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogMode>ONCE</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogMode>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogVerbosity>DEBUG</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogVerbosity>
      </req_hdr:LINFlags>
      <req_hdr:VACFlags>
        <req_hdr:validateRequest>true</req_hdr:validateRequest>
        <req_hdr:validateResponse>true</req_hdr:validateResponse>
        <req_hdr:logRequest>true</req_hdr:logRequest>
        <req_hdr:logResponse>true</req_hdr:logResponse>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerStrictMode>false</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerStrictMode>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogMode>ONCE</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogMode>
        <req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogVerbosity>DEBUG</req_hdr:ErrorHandlerLogVerbosity>
      </req_hdr:VACFlags>
    </req_hdr:ESBFlags>
    <req_hdr:internalHeader>
      <req_hdr:layerId>EXP</req_hdr:layerId>
      <req_hdr:operation>PartialUpdate</req_hdr:operation>
      <req_hdr:debugTrace>INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate.EXP_REST_PartialUpdate:N3f572585.134bd7a3.1d.17f7a43c82b.N790b > .EXP_PartialUpdate:N3f572585.134bd7a3.1d.17f7a43c82b.N7909</req_hdr:debugTrace>
    </req_hdr:internalHeader>
  </req_hdr:requestHeader>
</soapenv:Header>"
 messageID="N3f572585.134bd7a3.1d.17f7a43c82b.N7907"
 body="<soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <MinervaRequest xmlns="http://www.CustomerMinervaPartialUpdate">
    <cus:customerId xmlns:cus="http://www.CustomerMinervaPartialUpdate">3681419</cus:customerId>
    <customer>
      <parentalControl>Y</parentalControl>
      <pin>0000</pin>
    </customer>
    <customerAccount>
      <mpaaAccessLevel>
        <assetRatingId>4</assetRatingId>
      </mpaaAccessLevel>
      <pinRequired>Y</pinRequired>
      <tvRatingId>
        <tvRatingId>6</tvRatingId>
      </tvRatingId>
    </customerAccount>
  </MinervaRequest>
</soap-env:Body>"
 operation="PartialUpdate"
```

**Pre-production log snippet**

```
[DEBUG] | [09 Mar 2022 12:27:31 ] |[PartialUpdate  ] | {interfaceName: INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate,serverName: , consumer: UNKNOWN2.UNKNOWN2.UNKNOWN2,correlationId: N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fbc,message: Log of inbound Request at EXP layer <xml-fragment xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <MinervaRequest xmlns="http://www.CustomerMinervaPartialUpdate">
    <customer>
      <parentalControl>Y</parentalControl>
      <pin>1234</pin>
    </customer>
    <customerAccount>
      <mpaaAccessLevel>
        <assetRatingId>4</assetRatingId>
      </mpaaAccessLevel>
      <pinRequired>Y</pinRequired>
      <tvRatingId>
        <tvRatingId>6</tvRatingId>
      </tvRatingId>
    </customerAccount>
  </MinervaRequest>
</xml-fragment>,logTrace: <xml-fragment xmlns:req_hdr="ar.com.cablevision.common.RequestHeader">
  <req_hdr:layerId>EXP</req_hdr:layerId>
  <req_hdr:operation>PartialUpdate</req_hdr:operation>
  <req_hdr:debugTrace>INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate.EXP_REST_PartialUpdate:N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fbc</req_hdr:debugTrace>
</xml-fragment>}
[DEBUG] | [09 Mar 2022 12:27:31 ] |[PartialUpdate  ] | {interfaceName: INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate,serverName: , consumer: UNKNOWN2.UNKNOWN2.UNKNOWN2,correlationId: N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fbc,message: Log of inbound Request at VAC layer <xml-fragment xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <MinervaRequest xmlns="http://www.CustomerMinervaPartialUpdate">
    <cus:customerId xmlns:cus="http://www.CustomerMinervaPartialUpdate">3833255</cus:customerId>
    <customer>
      <parentalControl>Y</parentalControl>
      <pin>1234</pin>
    </customer>
    <customerAccount>
      <mpaaAccessLevel>
        <assetRatingId>4</assetRatingId>
      </mpaaAccessLevel>
      <pinRequired>Y</pinRequired>
      <tvRatingId>
        <tvRatingId>6</tvRatingId>
      </tvRatingId>
    </customerAccount>
  </MinervaRequest>
</xml-fragment>,logTrace: <xml-fragment xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req_hdr="ar.com.cablevision.common.RequestHeader">
  <req_hdr:layerId>VAC</req_hdr:layerId>
  <req_hdr:operation>PartialUpdate</req_hdr:operation>
  <req_hdr:debugTrace>INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate.EXP_REST_PartialUpdate:N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fbc > .EXP_PartialUpdate:N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fba > INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate.VAC_PartialUpdate:N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fb8</req_hdr:debugTrace>
</xml-fragment>}
[INFO ] | [09 Mar 2022 12:27:32 ] |[PartialUpdate  ] | {interfaceName: INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate,serverName: , consumer: UNKNOWN2.UNKNOWN2.UNKNOWN2,correlationId: N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fbc,message: Log of outbound Request at VAC layer <xml-fragment xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">
    <ns1:cookie>JSESSIONID=fkxvSt9bAN51t5KCw0hKskwhH3TUYveDbYJwP2Yy5mLQtiHXHrrx!1972117101; path=/; HttpOnly</ns1:cookie>
  </ns1:Response>
</xml-fragment>,logTrace: <xml-fragment xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req_hdr="ar.com.cablevision.common.RequestHeader">
  <req_hdr:layerId>VAC</req_hdr:layerId>
  <req_hdr:operation>PartialUpdate</req_hdr:operation>
  <req_hdr:debugTrace>INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate.EXP_REST_PartialUpdate:N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fbc > .EXP_PartialUpdate:N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fba > INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate.VAC_PartialUpdate:N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fb8</req_hdr:debugTrace>
</xml-fragment>}
[DEBUG] | [09 Mar 2022 12:27:33 ] |[PartialUpdate  ] | {interfaceName: INT_OSB_CustomerManagement.PartialUpdate,serverName: , consumer: UNKNOWN2.UNKNOWN2.UNKNOWN2,correlationId: N3f572545.52040fe5.N6a.17f6f47665c.N7fbc,message: Log of inbound Response at VAC layer <xml-fragment xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ns2:MinervaResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.CustomerMinervaPartialUpdate">
    <ns2:response>3833255</ns2:response>
    <ns2:statusCode>0</ns2:statusCode>
    <ns2:statusMessage>Customer 3833255 updated successfully.</ns2:statusMessage>
    <ns2:errorCode/>
    <ns2:errorMessage/>
    <ns2:httpStatus>200</ns2:httpStatus>
  </ns2:MinervaResponse>
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to the start of the managed server:

```
-Dcom.bea.osb.http.cookieAsNoComplexElement=true
```

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/develop/GUID-97AB0C09-A8CF-48CD-A173-C2A568B8A2DE.htm#OSBDV2491)